# How to use DownloadFileCompleted in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, download, zip, httpresponse

The code below works fine.
A zip file is created, a dialog pops up and ask you to save the zip.

I want to do something after the download of the dialog is closed without saving the zip.

There is a `DownloadFileCompleted` statement but how do you use it in my method?

`req.DownloadFileCompleted(...);` >>> where do i put this.

```
protected void CreateAndSaveZipFile(string path) 
{
    string startPath = path;
    string zipPath = Server.MapPath("Export");

    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    zipPath += now.ToString(@"\ddMMyyyyhhmmtt", new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
    zipPath += @"_Export.zip";
    ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath);

    string zipName = @"Export_" + now.ToString(@"\ddMMyyyyhhmmtt", new CultureInfo("en-GB")) +".zip";

    WebClient req = new WebClient();
    HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
    response.Clear();
    response.ClearContent();
    response.ClearHeaders();
    response.Buffer = true;
    response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + zipName);
    byte[] data = req.DownloadData(zipPath);
    response.BinaryWrite(data);
    response.End();
}
```

Can someone tell me how I can check if the dialog is closed or the file is successfully downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfilecompleted%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): description of `DownloadFileCompleted`:

> This event is raised each time an asynchronous file download operation
>   completes. Asynchronous file downloads are started by calling the
>   DownloadFileAsync methods.

So I see at least two issues in your code:

First: you're using synchronous method `DownloadData` instead of asynchronous [DownloadDataAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144191%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Second: you're trying to handle incorrect event. It should be [DownloadDataCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloaddatacompleted%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event.

Summary: use `DownloadDataAsync` method and handle `DownloadDataCompleted` event. Example of handling `DownloadDataCompleted` can be seen [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.downloaddatacompletedeventhandler%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: How do I use this in this code block. <br/>
<br/>
I have tried:<br/>

string zipPath = Server.MapPath("Export");<br/>
Uri zipUri = new Uri(zipPath);<br/>
byte[] data = req.DownloadFileAsync(zipUri, "file.zip");<br/><br/>

Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'byte[]'

Comment: @Babulaas your `data` will be available in event handler. See example of handling `DownloadDataComplete` here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.downloaddatacompletedeventhandler%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I am sorry for the last commend the format is wrong.

How do I use this in this code block.

I have tried:

string zipPath = Server.MapPath("Export");
Uri zipUri = new Uri(zipPath);
byte[] data = req.DownloadFileAsync(zipUri, "file.zip");

Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'byte[]'